# How to build Spring boot project which includes vaadin routes and static html pages

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, vaadin, vaadin-flow

I'm building a web app using `spring boot`, `vaadin`, and some static html pages (ui frameworks like bootstrap).

I want to have both `Vaadin` routes and static html pages in my project.

The static pages is just a basic `index.html` page which includes some `css` and `js`.

1) If i place the `index.html` in the webapp folder, it's accessible from the `www.localhost:8080/` url, but then i got error from vaadin, saying :

> the back-end doesn't accept POST requests to www.localhost:8080/

(because vaadin actually sends POST requests to that url)

2) If i add a `@Route("")` class, then the `index.html` is no lounger accessible, but then the back-end accepts the POST requests from the vaadin client...

3) I have no clue how to import static html to a `@Route` class. (no way with @HtmlImport)

Any Idea ?

Comment: Have you tried moving your vaadin servlet out of the way with the `vaadin.url-mapping` setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to cfrick for the clue. Have changed vaadin's servlet url mapping and left the index.html in the same place.

For people having same issues, everything's here: [Changing vaadin servlet url mapping](https://vaadin.com/docs/v13/flow/spring/tutorial-spring-configuration.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a spring-boot starter vaadin app, then below should work:

1) Place your static page (for example, `test.html`) under the `resources/static` . (There is an example from official Spring's demo page under [Add a Home Page section](https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/) with a short explanation about the appropriate folder)

2) Specify mapping rules using a `@Controller` annotated class after that

```java
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
@Controller
public class GreetingController {

        @GetMapping(value = "/ownPage")
        public String index() {
                return "test.html";
        }

}
```

3) Navigate to `yourURL\ownPage` or any path value specified inside the `@GetMapping`. This will return the `test.html` page

Comment: it's a solution, but i want my index page to get accessed from www.app.domain/